# What is wrong with my if-else syntax?

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

Currently new to java, and right now I'm doing an assignment involving if else statements. Can someone please why `javac` is reading my else as dangling? My syntax should be right unless I am missing something here.[image]

Comment: dont upload print screen! Updaload your code and your console out put here

Comment: Add the code as text to your question. Not as image.

Comment: Could you edit your question and copy/paste your code, and the error message as formatted text please? Having images of code (and errors) means that if somebody wants to help you, they have to type your code afresh.

Answer (score 6):

You have to remove your Semicolon after the if-statement. Otherwise the braces after the if are not executed.

I hope this will fix your Problem.

```
if(Statement);
{
    //The Content would not be executed in realtion to the if-statemen
}
```

Otherwise:

```
if(Statement)
{
    //The Content would be executed in realtion to the if-statemen
}
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answers as correct...

Answer (score 1):

remove the semicolon(;) after the if statement

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after your if. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `;` at the end of the line starting with `if`.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
if(...);
{
    ////
}
```

to

```
if(...)
{
    ////
}
```